# Improve error message when submitting an edit while an image is uploading

Tags: feature-request, uploader

When you click 'Save Edits' while an image upload is still processing, an error message is partially visible under the uploader:

> Body is missing.

[image]

Is it possible to

1. improve the visibility of the message, i.e. make sure it isn't partially covered by the uploader dialog
2. improve the clarity of the message, i.e. something like 'Please wait for the image upload to finish.'

Alternatively, disable the 'Save Edits' button while an image upload is in progress.

<sub>(The same situation probably occurs when posting the initial version of a question or answer, except that the button is named differently.)</sub>

Comment: +1 I was about to post the same feature request. On some phones one can't even see "body is missing" as the image is being uploaded. Demo: https://youtu.be/5ZUovAphDKo the issue is made worse by the fact that [image uploads are slow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350284/178179).